# How to search a generic collection object in java

Tags: java, collections

I am working on java and currently trying to search a list of object of a particular `DummyUserList` type.

```
public class DummyUserList implements Serializable {

        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String city;
        ----
        ----

        setter andd getter will go here.
    }
```

and

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<DummyUserList> searchListObj = new ArrayList<DummyUserList>();

        searchListObj.add(dummyUserList1);
        searchListObj.add(dummyUserList2);
        searchListObj.add(dummyUserList3);

        String toBeSearched = "Singhaniya";

        List<DummyUserList> result = searchListObj.stream()
            .filter(a -> Objects.equals(a.lastName, toBeSearched))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println("result--->" + result);

    }
```

Currently, the above code is searching `DummyUserList` object on the basis of `lastName`. It's working fine, but how can I pass a generic collection object to the `filter` method for searching?

I am trying in the following way: I am passing a generic collection object and it's supposed to be search and return a list of searched  object, but I'm getting a syntax error saying "**searchText** can not be resolved or is not a field".I want to do something like below code.

```
public static <T> List<T> search(Collection<T> collectionObject,
            String searchProperty, String searchText) {     

        List<T> result = collectionObject.stream()
            .filter(a -> Objects.equals(((List<T>) collectionObject).searchText))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
```

How do I pass a generic collection to the above method for searching? Is it possible to search a dynamic collection object?

Comment: Its a little confusing when you say *the above code is searching DummyUserList*

Comment: Why do you want to allow a generic `List` if its type should be a `DummyUserList` in order to let things work?

Comment: and the search method doesn't have a return statement either...you should read about [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you search a `Collection<T>`, each element of the collection is of type T. Not of type `List<T>`. So your cast doesn't make sense.

`Objects.equals()` takes two arguments, not one.

And you can't just pass the name of a property as a String (you would need reflection to access the field). Instead, you need a way to transform each T object into one of its properties of type String, in order to compare this property with the search text. So you need a `Function<T, String>`:

```
public static <T> List<T> search(Collection<T> collectionObject,
        Function<T, String> searchPropertyAccessor, String searchText) {     

    List<T> result = collectionObject.stream()
        .filter(item -> Objects.equals(searchPropertyAccessor.apply(item), searchText))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And you would call it this way:

```
List<User> foundUsers = search(users, User::getLastName, "Doe");
```

Note that I chose to rename your DummyUserList class to User, since what this class represents is a user, not a user list. Also note that I used a getter to access its last name, as public fields are a bad idea in general, and prevent the use of method references, which are quite handy and expressive.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JB Nizet. You save my day.